# Flex layout problem

Tags: apache-flex, layout

```
<mx:TextInput x="917" y="10" width="111"/>
```

I have many declarations like the abovein my flex code :

I wrote the following code, without thinking about how would it look
like on a resolution like 800x600 or even 1024x768.

So, now some portion of my UI is not displayed on machines
with above mentioned resolutions.

How do I solve this problem?

Is there any way to specify the x,y co-ordinates in percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify x/y coordinates in percentages, try this:

```
<!-- x = 60% of parent width, width = 20% of parent width, etc -->
<mx:TextInput x="{width*0.60}" y="{height*0.10}" width="20%"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

use constraints

```
<mx:TextInput left="10" top="10" width="111"/>
```

This will put the text input 10pxfrom the top and 10px from the left

Answer (score 1):

You need to use layout constraint, however this functionality is restricted to the parent container of the Text Input.

For instance you can only use constraint layout with a panel, canvas or application:
( left, right, top, or bottom )

For Application and Panel component you need to set the layout property to absolute. With the Canvas absolute is the default one.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
```

[Flex Documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=size_position_5.html)